# Typescript: cannot run type alias example

Tags: typescript

I have been looking into Typescript documentation and I stumbled across type alias and this example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html).

```
type DescribableFunction = {
  description: string;
  (someArg: number): boolean;
};
function doSomething(fn: DescribableFunction) {
  console.log(fn.description + " returned " + fn(6));
}
```

Running this example as it is returns nothing as the doSomething function is not called anywhere. To actually describe what the function property does in the DescribableFunction type, I was thinking doing something like this but it won't work.

```
type DescribableFunction = {
  description: string;
  (someArg: number): boolean;
};
function doSomething(fn: DescribableFunction) {
  console.log(fn.description + " returned " + fn(6));
}

const new_fn: DescribableFunction = {
  description: "test",
  () { // what do I put here?
    return true;
  },
};

doSomething(new_fn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign()` to instaniate an object assignable to this type.

```
const new_fn: DescribableFunction = Object.assign(
  (someArg: number) => { return true }, 
  { description: "test" }
)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIBFoGcDGAnAlgIwIZYDbQBiArgHYqgYD2ZsAvLAN7CywAmy6GkVtAXLCShMZAOYBuVrAAUSagFtoAQTRjBZEgqzQ0ASkFZq1QjjJSAvlIBm5SjTrtqAZUXRQACwziZ1soMRUTFwCYjs+Mj1maRRaeUIAOnxqMV8yBM4gngjYAGpYACJYNHcSNDJodkK82D8ZADY9PUsQWLJhWAqAdwB9PwCuYLxCUgocxgB5LAAraEoEnCQkDDEyGWk5N1V1Tq0dfQYAPmZi0vLYERI4CwAaWGkmDkHsh0EC0GRQIotgPRAnVxKTzeVLdPqRYBteLQJIpGRgvwZZ68Bx6IA)

Comment: thanks, it works but what about the input parameter?

Comment: @Spooky Oh I forgot that. But you can just add it to the function parameters

Comment: ohh right, yeah that works. I'll mark this as the solution

Comment: is there any reason to use this over, say an interface or a class though? @Tobias S.

Comment: I have never used such a call signature with additional props and I don't really see the point of it. I guess this could be usefull if you need to type a legacy JavaScript code base which uses stuff like this.